# The Brakhah 'Ha-Tov ve-ha-Meitiv' and Wine

Tags: halacha, blessing, grapes-wine

I think I vaguely remember that one of the occasions when one makes the brakhah 'ha-tov ve-ha-meitiv' is when you have been drinking wine and someone brings out another bottle of wine that is of a better quality than the one you have been drinking. Am I remembering right? Is it the practice nowadays to make make the brakhah in this situation? Are there any details or conditions to know about?

Comment: [Here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47069&st=&pgnum=335&hilite=) is a lengthy discussion as to why some people do not make this Bracha. Perhaps the question can be improved by asking why there are those who do not make this Bracha.

Comment: Thank you, Gershon. Looks like the answer to my question.

Comment: @GershonGold How would that improve the question? It would just change it. paquda wants to know when to say the blessing.

Comment: See [Shulchan Aruch (OC 175)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%94) and the accompanying [Mishna B'rura](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%94). This [article](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=10578) may also be of interest.

Comment: thank you, fred, that english article answered all my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I remembering right?

Yes.

> Is it the practice nowadays to make make the brakhah in this situation?

I've seen people do it and personally do it regularly. it's mentioned in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch which was written as a practical Sefer.

> Are there any details or conditions to know about?

Yes, quite a few. Here's the details as coded in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in section 49 -  [סימן מט - דיני ברכת היין וברכת הטוב והמטיב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0048_L2):

> **סעיף ח':** 
>   שָׁתוּ מִיַּיִן אֶחָד, בֵּין בְּתוֹךְ הַסְּעוּדָּה בֵּין שֶׁלֹּא בְּתוֹךְ הַסְּעוּדָּה וְהֵבִיאוּ לָהֶם יַיִן אַחֵר, אֵינוֹ מְבָרֵךְ עָלָיו בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן, כֵּיוָן שֶׁלֹּא נִמְלַךְ וְלֹא אַסַּח דַּעְתֵּהּ מִיַּיִן, אֲבָל מְבָרֵךְ עָלָיו הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב. וְכֵן אִם הֵבִיאוּ לָהֶם עוֹד יַיִן שְׁלִישִׁי, מְבָרְכִין גַּם כֵּן עָלָיו הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב. וְכֵן עַל הַרְבֵּה (מֵעֻבְדָּא דְּרַבִּי עַל כָּל חָבִית וְחָבִית שֶׁהָיָה פּוֹתֵחַ הָיָה מְבָרֵךְ הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב) (יְרוּשַׁלְמִי ברכות סוֹף פרק כיצד מברכין). ‏

If they drank wine (even before the meal) and then another type of wine was brought, one says the Bracha of הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב.

Same would apply if they bring the 3rd bottle of wine. And for all subsequent bottles.

But this only applies if they didn't decide - at any point - to not drink any more wine. That would be considered a *break*.

> **סעיף ט':** 
>   וְאִם הָיָה נִמְלַךְ מַמָּשׁ בְּאֹפֶן שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ שֵׁנִית בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן (עַיֵן לְקַמָּן סִימָן נ"ז), מְבָרֵךְ תְּחִלָּה הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב וְאַחַר כָּךְ בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן. ‏

If they did make a full *break* then the next bottle would require both blessings: first a הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב and then a בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן.

> **סעיף י':** 
>   הָא דִּמְבַרְכִין הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב, דַּוְקָא בִּסְתָם, שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָדוּעַ שֶׁהַשֵּׁנִי גָּרוּעַ מִן הָרִאשׁוֹן, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָדוּעַ אִם מְשֻׁבָּח מִן הָרִאשׁוֹן. אֲבָל אִם יָדוּעַ שֶׁהוּא גָּרוּעַ מִן הָרִאשׁוֹן, אֵין מְבָרְכִין עָלָיו. אַךְ כְּשֶׁהוּא בָּרִיא לַגּוּף יוֹתֵר מִן הָרִאשׁוֹן, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא גָּרוּעַ בַּטַעַם, מְבָרְכִין עָלָיו הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב. ‏

Caveat: A הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב is not made if you know that the next bottle is of inferior quality to the previous wine. If it's of similar quality then a הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב is made.

If it's inferior, but healthier, then a הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב is made. 
<sup>(E.g. Red wine is good for the heart, apparently).</sup>

> **סעיף י"א:** 
>   אֲפִלּוּ הָיָה לָהֶם מִתְּחִלָּה שְׁתֵּי יֵינוֹת, אֶלָּא שֶׁלֹּא הָיָה לִפְנָיו יַחַד כְּשֶׁבֵּרַךְ בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן, מְבָרֵךְ עַל הַשֵּׁנִי הַמְשֻׁבָּח הַטוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב. אֲבָל אִם הָיוּ שְׁנֵיהֶן לְפָנָיו עַל הַשֻּׁלְחָן, אֵינוֹ מְבָרֵךְ הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב, אֶלָּא בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן מְבָרֵךְ עַל הַמְשֻׁבָּח לִפְטוֹר גַּם אֶת הַגָּרוּעַ. ‏

Caveat: A הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב is only made if the 2nd (and subsequent) bottles of wine are not on the table when the original בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן was made.

If both are on the table, then בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן is made on the better wine and exempts the other one.

> **סעיף י"ב:** 
>   אֵין מְבָרְכִין הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב אֶלָּא אִם יֵשׁ עוֹד מִן הַיַּיִן הָרִאשׁוֹן וְרוֹצִים לִשְׁתּוֹת אֶת הַשֵּׁנִי מִשּׁוּם שִׁנּוּי יָיִן. אֲבָל אִם מֵחֲמַת שֶׁהַיַּיִן הָרִאשׁוֹן כָּלָה מְבִיאִין אֶת הַשֵּׁנִי, אֵין מְבָרְכִין עָלָיו. ‏

Caveat: A הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב is only made if the first wine isn't finished. If the first bottle is empty then no Bracha is made on the replacement bottle.

> **סעיף י"ג:** 
>   אֵין מְבָרְכִין הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב אֶלָּא כְּשֶׁיֵּשׁ אַחֵר עִמּוֹ שֶׁהוּא שׁוֹתֶה גַּם כֵּן מִשְּׁתֵּי הַיֵּינוֹת. דְּהָכִי מַשְׁמַע, הַטּוֹב לוֹ וְהַמֵּטִיב, לַחֲבֵרוֹ. וְהוּא הַדִּין אִם אִשְׁתּוֹ וּבָנָיו עִמּוֹ. אֲבָל אִם הוּא יְחִידִי, אֵינוֹ מְבָרֵךְ. ‏

Caveat: A הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב is not made when drinking by oneself. It's only made if at least one other person (wives and children qualify) drink from both bottles. Why? Because הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב implies 'good for me and for others'.

> **סעיף י"ד:** 
>   הָאוֹרֵחַ שֶׁמֵּסֵב אֵצֶל בַּעַל הַבַּיִת, אִם בַּעַל הַבַּיִת נוֹתֵן אֶת הַקַּנְקַן עַל הַשֻּׁלְחָן שֶׁיִּשְׁתֶּה מִי שֶׁיִּרְצֶה, כְּמוֹ שֶׁעוֹשִׂין בִּסְעוּדּוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת, אִם כֵּן, הַיַּיִן הוּא כְּמוֹ בְּשֻׁתָּפוֹת וּמְבָרְכִין הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב. אֲבָל אִם הַבַּעַל הַבַּיִת נוֹתֵן לְכָל אֶחָד כּוֹסוֹ, אֵין מְבָרְכִין הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב, כֵּיוָן שֶׁאֵין לָהֶם שֻׁתָּפוּת בְּיָיִן. וַאֲפִלּוּ הַבַּעַל הַבַּיִת אֵינוֹ מְבָרֵךְ (קע"ה). ‏

Caveat: If the host *controls the bottle* and pours each one their drinks, then a הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב is not made.

If the bottle is on the table and everybody can pour for themselves, then a הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב can be made - even if the host doesn't make a הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב (as he's not drinking more wine).

> **סעיף ט"ו:** 
>   אֶחָד יָכוֹל לְבָרֵךְ לְהוֹצִיא אֶת כֻּלָּם, וְיֹאמַר תְּחִלָּה: סַבְרִי וְכוּ' שֶׁיִּתְּנוּ לֵב לִשְׁמֹעַ וְיַעֲנוּ אָמֵן שֶׁיֵּצְאוּ בְּבִרְכָתוֹ. וְדַוְקָא כְּשֶׁיֵּשׁ לְכָל אֶחָד כּוֹסוֹ לְפָנָיו שֶׁיִּטְעֹם מִיָּד, שֶׁלֹּא יְהֵא הֶפְסֵק בֵּין הַבְּרָכָה לַשְּׁתִיָּה. ‏

Those who have the new wine in their cups ready to drink can be exempted from saying their own הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב by answering אָמֵן to another's הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב and then drinking immediately. In this case, the one making the communal הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב should preface it with סַבְרִי as a signal for them to pay attention.

> **סעיף ט"ז:** 
>   אִם מְבָרֵךְ בִּרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן עַל כּוֹס יַיִן אַחֵר, אֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ עָלָיו הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵטִיב, שֶׁהוּא יוֹצֵא בְּמַה שֶּׁאָמַר בְּבִרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב (קע"ה). ‏

No הַטּוֹב וְהַמֵּטִיב is said on the cup used for בִּרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן. Only a בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּפֶן is said, even if a new wine is used.